# How to extract contents between two strings in Python?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python.

I have a .txt file with almost ~500k lines of text. The general structure is like this:

> WARC-TREC-ID:
>
> hello
>
> my
>
> name
>
> is
>
> WARC-TREC-ID:
>
> example
>
> text
>
> WARC-TREC-ID:

I would like to extract all contents in between the "WARC-TREC-ID:" keywords.

This is what I have already tried:

```
    content_list = []

with open('C://Users//HOME//Desktop//Document_S//corpus_test//00.txt', errors = 'ignore') as openfile2:
    for line in openfile2:
        for item in line.split("WARC-TREC-ID:"):
            if "WARC-TREC-ID:" in item:
                content = (item [ item.find("WARC-TREC-ID:")+len("WARC-TREC-ID:") : ])
                content_list.append(content)
```

this returns an empty list.

I have also tried:

```
    import re

with open('C://Users//HOME//Desktop//Document_S//corpus_test//00.txt', 'r') as openfile3:
    
    m = re.search('WARC-TREC-ID:(.+?)WARC-TREC-ID:', openfile3)
    if m: 
        found = m.group(1)
```

and this causes a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
content_list = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:               #Iterate each line
        if 'WARC-TREC-ID:' in line:   #check if line contains 'WARC-TREC-ID:'
            content_list.append([])   #Append empty list
        else:
            content_list[-1].append(line)   #Append content

print(content_list)
```

Comment: I am getting a list index-out-of-range error on the following line: "content_list[-1].append(line) "

Comment: Try declaring  `content_list = [[]]`

Comment: I changed the declaration of content_list as well as removed any text before the first 'WARC-TREC-ID:' Now, I am getting the following error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 5720: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: I added an errors = 'ignore' parameter in my open file line and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach, you should pass your file content as `string` as [it expects a string argument, not file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). And this too, will only return the first occurrence of that string. You might want to use [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Answer (score -1):

For file that contains you data:

```
raw_data = open('data.txt', 'r').read()
result = [x for x in raw_data.split() if x != 'WARC-TREC-ID:']
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'example', 'text']
```